# Two Sum Leetcode problem using Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've recently gotten into Typescript and I'm solving some Leetcodes to learn.

[**Problem description:**](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/)

> Given an array of integers `nums` and an integer `target`, return *indices of the two numbers such that they add up to `target`*.
>
> You may assume that each input would have ***exactly* one solution**, and you may not use the *same* element twice.
>
> You can return the answer in any order.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - 2 <= `nums.length` <= 104
> - \$-10^9\$ <= `nums[i]` <= \$10^9\$
> - \$-10^9\$ <= `target` <= \$10^9\$
> - **Only one valid answer exists.**

I wrote this:

```
function twoSum(nums: number[], target: number): number[] {

    let map: Entry[] = [];
    
    type Entry = {
        readonly index: number, 
        readonly value: number, 
    }; 

    let result: number[] = []; 
    let test: any = nums.map((elem, index) => {
        let map_search = map.find((entry) => entry.value === target - elem); 
        if(map_search) {
            // contains suitable index
            result.push(index, map_search.index);
        } else {
            let new_entry: Entry = {
                index: index, 
                value: elem, 
            };
            map.push(new_entry);
        }
    })
    
    if(result) {
        return result;
    } else {
        return [];
    }
};
```

My solution works, but it feels a bit messy and inefficient in places. I feel like I'm not doing things in the proper Typescript way. Are there any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with the simple ones.

Use `const` instead of `let` when possible. It prevent accidental overwrites and it also better comunicates the intent. In fact, in your code, `const` is suitable in every single instance.

The `test` variable is unused and in fact, you should not call `map` at all if you're not mapping the array. You just wanna "forEach" the array or simply loop it using `for`.

Avoid using `any` type unless really necesary and it should stand for "any type is suitable here". If you just don't know what the type, better to use `unknown`.

Since `result` can only be `Array`, asking `if (result)` is meaningless because it will always be true.

No need to write semicolons in ts/js. At least you're consistent in using them, but it's very easy to go inconsistent without noticing. Most professionals probably use a linter configured to disallow them.

I would also change the return type if nothing is found to null rather then empty array and actually instead of `number[]` your can return `[number, number]` since it will always have two elements. If we were not constrained to exactly one solution, it would make sense to return `[number,number][]` and then empty array for "not found any solution" would fit.

Now for the performance. Time complexity of your solution is `O(n^2)`.

From specification

> each input would have exactly one solution

We can return as soon as we find it.

We can also infer that each element of `nums` array is unique. And so we can construct an inverted map and use it to better the algorithm time complexity into `O(n)`. However we sacrficice `O(n)` extra memory for the `Map` (although your solution does that too).

```
function twoSum(nums: number[], target: number): [number, number] | null {
    const visitedIndicesByValue = new Map<number, number>()

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        const diff = target - nums[i]
        if (visitedIndicesByValue.has(diff)) {
           return [visitedIndicesByValue.get(diff), i]
        } else {
           visitedIndicesByValue.set(nums[i], i)
        }
    }

    return null
}
```